# Default mode in Crypto.Cipher.AES.new

Tags: aes, pycrypto

In the method `Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(key, mode, *args, **kwargs)`, what is the default mode when only one parameter is provided:

```
cipher = AES.new(key)
Crypted = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
```

The documentation just says:

> mode (One of the supported MODE_* constants) – The chaining mode to use for encryption or decryption. If in doubt, use MODE_EAX.

Comment: Note that the use of the legacy PyCrypto is insecure. Instead, the successor PyCryptodome should be used, which forces a specification of the mode, otherwise an error message is displayed: _TypeError: new() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mode'_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECB. This is detailed in the [docs](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/). (I'm not certain which ones you're looking at. It's possible the docs have been improved since the version you have.)

> new(key, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Create a new AES cipher
>
> Parameters:
>
> key (byte string) - The secret key to use in the symmetric cipher. It must be 16 (AES-128), 24 (AES-192), or 32 (AES-256) bytes long.
>
> mode (a MODE_* constant) - The chaining mode to use for encryption or decryption. Default is MODE_ECB.
>
> ...

As a rule, I would not rely on a default here. It has a major impact on the encryption, and is important for anyone reading the code to be certain about. (Also, ECB is almost always the wrong mode to use. It's only secure in very controlled situations.)